# How to redirect a PDF link to a different domain with the same PDF file using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this link on my html website `http://html-website.com/F2F_Strategic_Plan.pdf` and I want it do redirect to my wordpress site `https://wordpress-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/F2F_Strategic_Plan.pdf`

I have uploaded already the same pdf in my wordpress site, so far I have tried this rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule http://html-website.com/F2F_Strategic_Plan.pdf https://wordpress-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/F2F_Strategic_Plan.pdf [R=302,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^F2F_Strategic_Plan\.pdf$ https://wordpress-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/F2F_Strategic_Plan.pdf [R=302,L,NC]
```

but still not working, any help will do, thanks

Here is the actual script inside my htaccess, all this is working except for the pdf's

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Redirect non WordPress pages to corresponding post
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cafarmtofork.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.cafarmtofork.com$
RewriteRule ^$ https://theappliancejudge.co.uk [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^CA_NutritionIncentiveProgram\.htm$ https://theappliancejudge.co.uk/ca_nutritionincentiveprogram [R=301,L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Could you please do let us know if you are seeing any errors when you try this url in your browser?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 when I enter this url http://html-website.com/F2F_Strategic_Plan.pdf it just goes to that url and does not redirect to the wordpress site which has that pdf also, so it just opens to the old url

Comment: IMHO if I am not wrong rule should be inside `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and `RewriteEngine ON` should be done too, just checking these are taken care right? To make sure nothing missing here.

Comment: yes, its inside the <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>, I am just specifying that particular line

Comment: Sure, and `RewriteEngine ON` is also before this right? Then only rules will work. To make sure before troubleshooting we are all set with file:)

Comment: Your rule `RewriteRule ^F2F_Strategic_Plan\.pdf$ https://wordpress-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/F2F_Strategic_Plan.pdf [R=302,L,NC]`  is correct. Just place it just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: @anubhava, Thank you anubhava sir for enlightening here I was trying to help OP, you could add this as an answer. Thank you and cheers.

Comment: Thank you also @RavinderSingh13 for the help, I think all the answers you gave is correct it just need to go to its proper location

Comment: @FrancisAlvinTan, Sorry man I couldn't help :( tried my best, cheers and keep sharing on this great site.